# ArcPy in_memory\ vanishing from ToC

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, in-memory

ArcGIS 10.1 - attempting to add a derived raster layer to the ToC.  This works in 10.2.  In 10.1 I get a screen flash and nothing added.

```
rasterized = r'in_memory\rasterized'
arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(poly_shp, field, rasterized, None, cellsize)
res = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(rasterized, 'tmplyr')
rasterlyr = res.getOutput(0)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '*')[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, rasterlyr, "TOP")
```

Where:
poly_shp = unicode vector name
field = unicode field name from the poly_shp
rasterized = str
cellsize = float

Adding:

```
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

has no effect.

Edit:

---

I know that the in_memory workspace is functioning properly as the following try is hit on subsequent runs.

```
try:
        arcpy.Delete_management(rasterized)
        arcpy.AddMessage('Overwriting in_memory raster')
except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(poly_shp, field, rasterized, None, cellsize)
```

You have missed out cell alignment parameter, so try

```
arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(poly_shp, field, rasterized, "","", cellsize)
```

With that parameter set your code executes and a raster is added to my TOC. If that correction does not work then it strongly suggests either the poly_shp, field or cellsize parameters are invalid.

Comment: Using: `res = arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(roi,abundance,rasterized,"MAXIMUM_AREA","",cellsize)` had no effect.  Replacing `"MAXIMUM_AREA"` with `""` also had no effect.

Comment: Your code worked for me when  I included the missing parameter. Please amend your question to show EXACTLY what your your variables hold

Comment: updated - can you update your answer with the datatypes you are passing in?  It amazes me that this works in 10.2 and fails in 10.1.